# Dynamic Programming : The Zipper

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Doing a little practice on dynamic programming problems in preparation for my final and I found this problem that stumped me.

Zippers:  Given three strings, you are to determine whether the third string can be formed by combining the characters in the first two strings. The first two strings can be mixed arbitrarily, but the characters from each must stay in their original order in the third string.

For example, consider forming "tcarete" from "cat" and "tree":
String A: c a t
String B: t r e e
String C: t c a r e t e

As you can see, we can form string C by selecting the first charcter of "tree", followed by the first 2 characters of "cat", followed by the second and third characters of "tree", followed by the last charcter of "cat" and "tree" respectively.

As a second example, consider forming "catrtee" from "cat" and "tree":
String A: c a t
String B: t r e e
String C: c a t r t e e

The answer for this input is also 'yes'

Output:  Output yes if A and B can be combined (zippered) into string C.
  Output no if A and B cannot be combined to form C.

So basically we want to see if the third string, C can be formed from A and B. 
something like 
C T R T E A E would output No.
My biggest problem is the fact that cat and tree both have the letter T in it. So I can't just run an algorithm that checks if one letter comes after the other. Any help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are reviewing dynamic programming, it should be rather natural to use it for this problem.

Now, let's think about it this way:

1. For the whole String C, if it is a mixture of A and B, then its first character must be either the first character of A, or the first one in B;
2. Now step further, the first `k` characters in C, `kA` < `k` of them must be from A, and `kB` = `k` - `kA` of them must be from B.

From this, it is not hard to find out an algorithm that use O(min(len(A), len(B))) space and use O(len(C) * min(len(A), len(B))) to run.

Hint: for each step through C, some of the positions in A must be "On", while the others are "off". In the end if all the character in both strings are consumed, then C can be generated from A and B.